# Implementing a toggle in ionic using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am following up a tutorial I found here http://codepen.io/keval5531/details/LVYROp/

As a result I am able to come up with the below solution on my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.value = false;
 $scope.toggleChange = function(){
   if($scope.value == false) {
   $scope.value = true;  
   }
   else
     $scope.value = false;
    console.log('testToggle changed to '+$scope.value);
   };
  });
```

Now I have this in my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
   <br><br>
    <ion-toggle ng-model=value ng-change="toggleChange()">Test toggle</ion-toggle>
    </div></body>
</html>
```

Here is a plunk demo I have made
https://plnkr.co/edit/MUp7QckDCgg50FvcfGeG?p=preview
My challenge is that based on the codepen tutorial I am learning with, nothing happens on my display. Kindly assist!

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of issues here. The first issue is that you didn't include the angular.js file, this is the core of angular and is required. Also, the angular source that you did use didn't work. Here is a fully functional example

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  
  $scope.value = false;
  
  $scope.toggleChange = function(){
    if($scope.value == false) {
       $scope.value = true;  
    }
    else {
       $scope.value = false;
       console.log('testToggle changed to '+$scope.value);
    }
   };
  
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.12/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.12/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
   <br><br>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model=value ng-change="toggleChange()">Test toggle</ion-toggle>
 </div></body>
</html>
```

I used an alert for dramatic effect. 
Regards :)

Comment: Can I achieve thesame result using this:

Comment: $scope.value = false;
 $scope.toggleChange = function(){
   if($scope.value == false) {
   $scope.value = true;  
   }
   else
     $scope.value = false;
    console.log('testToggle changed to '+$scope.value);
   };

Comment: Done. it will always be unchecked now though

Comment: I have actually achieved this before, but I want it a toggle

Comment: Why will it always be unchecked #any ideas

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve. If you just want to see what value the toggle is when you press it, my first example was correct